# Receiving useContext error that disappears once the app restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am receiving this useContext error "React Hook "useContext" is called in function "contacts" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks" the error goes away when I restart the app but appears anything I mess with the code files underneath:

Contact.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import ContactContext from '../../context/contact/contactContext';
import { ContactItems } from './ContactItems';

const contacts = () => {
    const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext);

    const {contacts} = contactContext;

    return(
        <Fragment>
            {contacts.map(contact =>(
                <ContactItems key={contact.id} contact={contact}/>
            ))}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default contacts
```

contactContext.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

const ContactContext = createContext();

export default ContactContext;
```

ContactState.js

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import ContactContext from './contactContext';
import contactReducer from './contactReducer';
import {
    ADD_CONTACT,
    DELETE_CONTACT,
    SET_CURRENT,
    CLEAR_CURRENT,
    UPDATE_CONTACT,
    FILTER_CONTACT,
    CLEAR_FILTER
} from "./types"

const ContactState = props =>{

    const initialState = {
        contacts:[
            {
                id:1,
                name:'Alex Antoine',
                email:'a@gmail.com',
                phone:'111-111-111',
                type:'Personsal'
            },

            {
                id:2,
                name:'Matt White',
                email:'mwhite@gmail.com',
                phone:'111-111-111',
                type:'Personsal'
            },

            {
                id:3,
                name:'Johnny Sinns',
                email:'sinns@gmail.com',
                phone:'111-111-111',
                type:'Personsal'
            }
        ]
    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(contactReducer, initialState);

    //Actions

    //Add Contact

    //Delete Contact

    //Set Current Contact

    //Clear Contact

    //Update Contact

    //Filter Contacts

    //Clear Filter

    return (
        <ContactContext.Provider value={{
            contacts:state.contacts
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </ContactContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default ContactState;
```

Any help and explanation on why this happens are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, functions that represent components are named in PascalCase. You `contacts` component function should be named `Contacts`. Renaming this should fix that error.

The error message you shared in the question itself clearly states this as well.